# how to get all child data and then delete in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have mapped one to many as follows

```
//TourPackage model
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "packages", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Itinerary> itineraries;

public Set<Itinerary> getItineraries() {
    return itineraries;
}
```

in itinerary model

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="packages_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private TourPackage packages;
```

now my update function, update form returns tourPackage and multiple itinerary, so what I want to do is delete all previous itinerary and insert new ones. Where I have written `//null returned` to my knowledge should return all the itinerary of that package but returns null.

```
@PostMapping("/update-tour-package")
public String updateTourPackage(@ModelAttribute("tourPackage") TourPackage tourPackage, @RequestParam String[] day, @RequestParam String[] itinerary_title, @RequestParam String[] itinerary_description, @RequestParam String[] itinerary_altitude) {
    
    TourPackage tour = this.tourPackageService.saveTourPackage(tourPackage);

    this.itineraryRepo.deleteAll(tour.getItineraries());//null returned for itinerary

    for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
        Itinerary ite = new Itinerary();
        ite.setPackages(tour);
        ite.setDay(day[i]);
        ite.setTitle(itinerary_title[i]);
        ite.setDescription(itinerary_description[i]);
        ite.setAltitude(itinerary_altitude[i]);
        this.itineraryRepo.save(ite);
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

am I doing it right? please point me in right direction. Please comment if I should provide more context to the question.

Comment: Because unless you have config elsewhere to set an existing TourPackage as the model object, @ModelAttribute("tourPackage") TourPackage tourPackage will be a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because unless you have config elsewhere to set an existing TourPackage as the model object, `@ModelAttribute("tourPackage") TourPackage tourPackage` will be a new instance.

If you want to modify an existing instance then send through a hidden field with the ID and add a method inn your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute
public TourPackage getTourPackage(@RequestParam(name = "tourPckageId", required = false) Long id){
   //load from repo if id is not null or otherwise new instance
}
```

Now the updateTourPackage method will receive the existing instance returned by the above.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods

Answer (score 1):

You should change code like this:

```
    @Transactional
    public void deleteAll(TourPackage tourPackage) { // Some param here
      TourPackage tour = this.tourPackageService.saveTourPackage(tourPackage);

       this.itineraryRepo.deleteAll(tour.getItineraries());//null returned for itinerary

       for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
         // Do the same with your code.
        }


    }

    @PostMapping("/update-tour-package")
    public String updateTourPackage(@ModelAttribute("tourPackage") TourPackage tourPackage) {
      tourPacakageService.deleteAll(tourPackage);
 
    }
```

Here is why:

- You set @OneToMany with fetchType is Lazy => itineraries will get latter when you need it as long as you are in a session or persistence context.
- In spring JPA, the default scope of persistence context is transaction. After you call saveTourPackage(tourPackage) the transaction has end. That why you will get null for it itineraries.